# Sending a TCP RST packet with net.Server? [Node.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, tcp, v8

```
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(function(c) { //'connection' listener
  c.write('hello and welcome\r\n');
  c.on('data', function(data) {
      if(data.length > 0) {
        c.write("Validating...\r\n");
        c.pause();
      }
      setTimeout(function() {
        c.resume();
        c.write(data+'\r\n');
      }, 5000);
  });
});
server.listen(8124, function() { //'listening' listener
  console.log('server bound');
});
```

So, how exactly do TCP RST packets work. It isn't like just sending a HTTP response, right? Is it possible to do this in Node?

Comment: There is nothing in the [current documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html) that makes that possible, I'm glad to say.